# Mutual update between two classes of same superclass

Tags: c++, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I have an OpenGL application with two main parts (viewers), with a main loop as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gp::viewers::PatternViewer pViewer;
    gp::viewers::MeshViewer mViewer;

    while (!pViewer.shouldClose() && !mViewer.shouldClose())
    {
        pViewer.makeCurrent();
        pViewer.mainLoop();
        pViewer.swap();

        mViewer.makeCurrent();
        mViewer.mainLoop();
        mViewer.swap();

        glfwWaitEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;

}
```

It happens that a user interaction with one viewer should propagate a change to the other viewer. My gut instinct says to update the loop as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gp::viewers::PatternViewer pViewer;
    gp::viewers::MeshViewer mViewer;

    while (!pViewer.shouldClose() && !mViewer.shouldClose())
    {
        pViewer.makeCurrent();
        pViewer.mainLoop();
        pViewer.swap();

        mViewer.makeCurrent();
        mViewer.mainLoop();
        mViewer.swap();

        // UPDATE HERE
        mViewer.update(pViewer);
        pViewer.update(mViewer);

        glfwWaitEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;

}
```

But in that case, PatternViewer needs to know about MeshViewer, and MeshViewer needs to know about PatternViewer - a circular dependency. Moreover, it isn't clear if mViewer.update(pViewer) should update pViewer with whatever updates are available from mViewer, or vice versa. It seems to me that it should be the former - mViewer should know what updates to propagate, not pViewer.

It should be mentioned that PatternViewer and MeshViewer both inherit from abstract superclass Viewer.

Is there any way of resolving this circular dependency? Is there an accepted way/design pattern for handling this case?

Comment: Couldn't you make a helper class, which does both updates, and when you need to update, you call the object of it. In constructor it would take a pointer to two other objects and do updates in a manner that is consistent.

Comment: You could try an event based approach: Put user interactions into a event and send that to all viewers, and each viewer is filtering for the events it's interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the information to be shared between viewers visible in a `Viewer`, that is, in the base class? If so, then a abstract `Viewer` needs to know how to update from another abstract `Viewer` but there's no need for each concrete `Viewer` such as `PatternViewer` or `MeshViewer` to know about another concrete `Viewer` — in other word, there's no need for a circular dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The standard pattern for this case is MVC (Model, View, Controller).

With this pattern, neither viewer knows about the other at all. The data that's shared between the views is in the Model. When a viewer needs to update something, it updates the model (though if you're really following MVC, the views should just display output, and input should come from the controllers).

Along with the raw data, the model keeps a list of all current views on the data. When the model gets updated, it propagates the change(s) out to all the views.

Note that there are many variations on MVC. A few eliminate the "controller" part in favor of something closer to what you're doing: with the Views doing both input and output (but still moving the common data into a Model).